# pythonic way to extract a slice from 3d array according to mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an **MxNxD** array I and also a binary **MxN** mask M.

Let's say that there are **k** 1s in M. What I want is to extract a **kxD** array that contains all the D-length vectors corresponding to the 1s in the mask.

I can get the indices of these vectors in I by calling **numpy.nonzero()** but I can't find a nice compact way of getting my slice without horrible loops.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
In [283]: A = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
In [284]: M = np.array([[1,0,1],[0,1,0]],dtype=bool)
In [285]: A
Out[285]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
In [286]: M
Out[286]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]])
In [287]: I,J = np.nonzero(M)
In [288]: I,J
Out[288]: (array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 2, 1]))
In [289]: A[I,J,:]
Out[289]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

Since `M` is masking the initial dimensions, it can be simplified to

```
A[np.nonzero(M)]
```